# $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos^{2n} 24\pi x,x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to know whether this function is riemann integrable or not 
 $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\cos^{2n} (24\pi x),x\in[0,1]$

well, at $x=0$ we see that $f(x)=1$, $x=1/48$, $f(x)=0$, but I am unable to find out the exact pointwise limit function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$|q|<1\Longrightarrow q^k\xrightarrow [k\to\infty]{}0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $|\cos \theta | \leq 1$. If $|\cos \theta| < 1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \cos^{2n} \theta$ will be equal to ... ?